# Map is broken on GeoEXT when dir=rtl in chrome (pics inside)

Tags: openlayers-2, geoext, ext-js

I've created a GeoExt app with simple map and east panel.
When I change the dir to rtl it works fine in FF but in Chrome the map isn't scrollable.

LTR:

[image]

RTL:

[image]

Here is the link to my site (with the bug)

```
http://77.235.53.170/LehavimExt/
```

I created a JSFiddle example and in the fiddle window it works fine.
http://jsfiddle.net/uvY3r/

So now I'm clueless what is the problem.

This is the code I use :

```
 var map;
var format = 'image/png';
var epsg4326 = new OpenLayers.Projection('EPSG:4326');
var epsg900913 = new OpenLayers.Projection('EPSG:900913');

Ext.Loader.setConfig({
    enabled: true,
    disableCaching: false,
    paths: {
        GeoExt: "js/GeoExt",
        Ext: "js/ext-4.2.1.883/src"
    }
});

Ext.require([
    'Ext.container.Viewport',
    'Ext.state.Manager',
    'Ext.window.MessageBox',
    'GeoExt.panel.Map'
]);

Ext.application({
    name: 'Lehavim Ext',
    launch: function () {

        var extent = new OpenLayers.Bounds(34.79, 31.36, 34.834, 31.38).transform(epsg4326, epsg900913);
        map = new OpenLayers.Map('map', {
                units: 'm',
                restrictedExtent: extent,
                controls: [
                new OpenLayers.Control.PanZoomBar(),
                new OpenLayers.Control.Navigation(),
                new OpenLayers.Control.ScaleLine(),
                new OpenLayers.Control.MousePosition()  ,
                new OpenLayers.Control.LayerSwitcher()                  
            ],
        projection: epsg900913,
        displayProjection: epsg4326 //Is used for displaying coordinates in appropriate CRS by MousePosition control
        });

        var resolutions = OpenLayers.Layer.Bing.prototype.serverResolutions.slice(16, 20);
        var osm = new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM("OSM", null, { zoomOffset: 16, resolutions: resolutions });

        map.addLayers([osm]);
        var pos = new OpenLayers.LonLat(34.8161900, 31.370).transform(epsg4326, map.getProjection());

        map.setCenter(pos, 16);

        Ext.create('Ext.container.Viewport', {
        layout: 'border',
        rtl:true,
        bodyBorder: true,
        defaults: {
            collapsible: false,
            split: true,
            //margins: '0 0 0 0',
            bodyPadding: 15
        },
        items: [
        {
            //title: 'Header',
            region: 'north',
            height:50,
            html: 'Menu'
        },
        {
            title: 'Navigate',
            region:'east',            
            collapsible: true,            
            width: 250,            
            html: 'Secondary content like navigation links could go here'
        },
        {
            region: "center",
            id: "mappanel",            
            xtype: "gx_mappanel",
            map: map,
            stateful: true,
            stateId: 'mappanel',
        }
        ]
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is that needs to add style to Openlayers Container (by default the position is absolute which doesnt work well in RTL mode.

```
{
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
}
```